# The thing that scares me the most are the little oranges in its stomach

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Sally says "The thing that scares me the most are the little oranges in its stomach."
at 4:50 in the TV drama "3rd Rock From the Sun S1E3 Dick's First Birthday".
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tgj83qt7fqA

Please notice that "thing" is singular whereas "oranges" is plural.
I'm wondering which one of the following statements about the sentence is correct.

1. It is grammatically correct and perfectly makes sense.
2. It is grammatically incorrect and most people frown upon it.
3. It is grammatically incorrect, but most people think it is natural and don't care.
4. Else.

Comment: Option 3 doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @snailboat So what do you think the correct answer is?

Comment: Also, perhaps consider: *"What scares me the most are the little oranges in its stomach"*, and *"What scared me the most were the little oranges in its stomach"* -- perhaps, maybe, could be interesting, for a rainy day. :)

Comment: And perhaps someone could provide an evaluation of: *"The thing that scares me the most **is** the little oranges in its stomach."* Is there a mismatch in number there, and if there is, is it acceptable?

Comment: Makoto, I hope you will reconsider accepting [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/77574/6700), which claims that the sentence uses deliberate inversion for emphasis. I think that's quite wrong, and it gives you a false impression, both of common grammatical errors and of inversion for emphasis.

Comment: @BenKovitz "*The little oranges in its stomach are the thing that scares me the most.*" seems to me grammatically correct. So is the inversion. No?

Comment: "The little oranges…are…" is grammatically correct, but that doesn't answer your question, which is about "The thing that scares me the most are…" "The thing that scares me the most are…" is not [inversion](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inversion) because "The thing that ---- the most is ----" is the normal word order. The emphasis is strongest when you start the sentence with "The thing…" The sentence you asked about is a common, natural grammatical error, which is good to understand as you're learning English.  Inversion just isn't relevant here.

Comment: To properly judge this kind of thing, you need _feeling_ for the language more than you need an exact theory, and you can only get that feeling with experience. Here on ELL, we can't give you feeling for the language, but we can tell you hints to help you develop feeling for the language as you gain more experience. I think the "inversion" answer is misleading, because it leads you away from understanding how people really use stock phrases for emphasis and how grammatical errors commonly occur in casual speech. It also misleads about how common inversion for emphasis really is.

Comment: @BenKovitz "*The sentence you asked about is a common, natural grammatical error*" Could you tell me how Sally should say instead?

Comment: Yes: "The thing that scares me the most **is** the little oranges in its stomach." My answer explains more (briefly, in a playful way) about the conflicting grammatical pressures that often lead people to make an error here and in many similar sentences.

Comment: @BenKovitz A grammar rule says "*Singular subjects need singular verbs, and plural subjects need plural verbs.*" This seems very basic. Could it be a common grammatical error if a native speaker violates the rule?

Comment: Yes. My answer provides some more details. The full topic is complicated, but many sentences have _conflicting pressures_ that confuse speakers while they're talking, and they sometimes make mistakes. This happens most commonly with subject-verb agreement, because sometimes the speaker isn't sure, without thinking carefully, which noun a verb should agree with. Sometimes there is no fully satisfactory way to word a sentence, as in [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20886/6700) about a different kind of "agreement" problem.

Answer (score 10):

It is grammatically incorrect, but most people think it is natural and don't care.

The simple subject is **thing**, which is singular, so the verb must be singular to agree with it. Notice that in the subordinate clause, **scares** is singular, agreeing with **thing**.

The speaker got confused because it seems strange to say that a singular thing "is" a plural like **oranges**. That's more than one orange, right? Perhaps the speaker could revise the sentence so the subject is "the things that scare me the most". But there are two problems with that. First, the idiomatic phrase is "the thing that scares me the most". If you say "the things that scare me the most", that's weaker, because then you aren't pointing out the #1 scariest thing. Second, the speaker starts saying the sentence before choosing the main verb. By the time the speaker has said "The thing that scares me the most", it's too late to change it. At that point, the speaker sees **oranges** coming up ahead, and scrambles to choose the verb. "Is" sounds wrong because of **oranges**; "are" sounds wrong because of **thing**. Oh no!! There's no time to think this through, so the speaker compromises and chooses a verb to agree with **oranges**, dimly sensing that something is wrong.

And then life goes on.

Answer (score 5):

The grammar error is caused by a rough simplification of the sentence, which makes it much shorter. The simplified sentence from the question is grammatically incorrect, but good enough to understand it:

> The thing that scares me the most are the little oranges in its stomach.

I see it as a **contraction** of the longer sentence:

> The thing that scares me the most ***is* the fact that there are** the little oranges in its stomach.

The full sentence is grammatically correct. When leaving out part of it, the grammar breaks, but the remainder is still "somehow good enough" to understand it.
The use of "are" instead of "is" could be seen as an adjustment atempting to fix the grammar.

In summary:

**It is grammatically incorrect, but most people easily understand it anyway, so they accept it as natural and don't care enough to complain.**

Seems to be close enough to be seen as case 3:
It is grammatically incorrect, but most people think it is natural and don't care.
Or else, Else.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it should be "The thing that scares me the most *is* the little oranges in its stomach." because *thing* is a singular.

"the little oranges in its stomach" is a singular thing in this case, meaning having little oranges in his stomach is what scares her.

However "The things that scare me the most *are* the little oranges in its stomach." is also correct, except it implies that each individual orange in its stomach would be scary on its own.

Comment: Yes, typo.  Corrected, thx!

Answer (score 0):

> For if knowledge is power, then **a god am I**. --- The Riddler, *Batman Forever*, 1995

Please note that "a god" is a third-person noun phrase.   It does not agree with the verb form "am".

Nevertheless, it is grammatically correct and perfectly sensible.   This is an inversion.   Normal word order for the clause is "I am a god."   The verb "am" agrees with its subject "I", and the third-person complement doesn't need to agree with anything.   The inversion simply lends emphasis to the complement.   The phrasing "a god am I" reads like "I am ***a god!***"

The same thing happens in your example:   Those little oranges are a scary thing.   The verb "are" agrees with the subject "oranges".   The complement "a scary thing" doesn't agree with anything.   This subject/verb agreement survives the inversion:   A scary thing are those little oranges.

> Was that over the top?

That is the Riddler's next line in the scene.   Here, "over the top" means excessively dramatic or excessively emphatic.   That is an accurate description of his prior line.   He just delivered that emphatic word order in a strongly emphatic tone -- loud, rough, deep, and slow.

The beauty of this example is that the source material itself immediately indicates the reason for the Riddler's use of the inversion.   He clearly intended the phrasing "a god am I" to be as emphatic, as poetic and as dramatic as possible.   He *intends* to be over the top.   He could have said "I am a god", but that ordinary statement lacks the additional impact that the inversion grants.

The emphasis in your example is not over the top.   It's a natural emphasis that many native speakers understand and use instinctively, without even noticing or recognizing the grammatical mechanism involved.

In other words, it's grammatically correct, perfectly sensible, and utterly common.

Comment: The inversion that you describe is indeed a strong form of emphasis. But I don't think that's what's happening in the "little oranges" sentence. I think most people hear that as an error, not as emphasis. People often hem and haw while or right after saying it. Understanding it as inversion would misunderstand the emphasis, which comes from the stock phrase "the thing that ---- the most is ----", which requires a singular verb for the emphasis to make sense. If "oranges" were the simple subject, you would say "things" to agree with it, spoiling the emphatic phrase.

Comment: If you still think that the "oranges" sentence uses the "a god am I" inversion, could you add something more to your answer about _why_? Right now, it seems that you've run off on an unexplained analogy with something unrelated. What's the connection?

Comment: What I don't understand is why you'd claim a stock phrase or cliché produces emphasis.  Style guides consistently recommend avoiding them precisely because tired phrasing *cannot* produce either emphasis or clarity.  What you don't seem to understand are that complements often precede the copula (cf. "a merry band are we" and "blessed are the meek") and that Sally is reacting not to the oranges themselves but to their placement and use.  Had Sally let the verb agree with "things", the latter fact would not be evident in the sentence itself.  Choice of subject is meaningful.

Comment: I'm writing tersely because these are comments. Some more info is in my answer. Authorities and strict rules seldom describe the real conventions by which people communicate through the language or how speakers think about sentence. E.g. style guides recommend against clichés _because_ people use them for emphasis so much, they lose their power. Inversion for emphasis is very strong but also very rare (which is partly why it's so strong). The cliché of "the thing that ---- the most is ----" communicates by its familiarity, and the singular verb is needed to give "the most" maximum impact.

Comment: More to the point, grammatical errors involving subject-verb agreement are fairly common in practice, especially where there are two nouns that superficially seem to command agreement with the verb. This is an excellent question because it focuses on a common kind of grammatical error—which is truly valuable for a learner to know about. Textbooks seldom talk about this kind of error, and indeed you can't figure it out on the basis of rules alone. You can only understand what's going on through experience, familiarity with clichés, empathy for speakers engaged in everyday sloppy speech, etc.