# Is it perfectly natural to end sentences with Prepositions?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, grammaticality-in-context, grammar-myths

There are numerous myths relating to grammatical dos and don’ts, many of which were drummed into us at school. The one that stubbornly refuses to budge from my mind is the diktat "never begin a sentence with a conjunction such as *and* or *but*" and "never end a sentence with preposition such as *about*, *with*, *on*, etc." but I would like to hear from all if it is perfectly natural to end a sentence with preposition in modern English?

Comment: This has been asked at Stack Exchange before: **[When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)** Yes, it is perfectly natural. "*Here's to the land you've torn out the **heart of** \ Mississippi, find yourself another country to be **[part of](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7fgB0m_y2I)***."

Comment: Your other question is also conveniently addressed at http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52239/why-do-people-incorrectly-begin-a-sentence-with-the-word-but. :)