# "My wife and I am": Singular / Plural and the rule of proximity issue

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, proximity-agreement

"My wife and I am" = one family, a singular number. Therefore satisfies  the use of "am" for both number and proximity issues.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 4):

> *My wife and I are/is ...*

Generally, a subject with the form of a coordination of noun phrases linked by "and" takes a plural verb.

"My wife and I" is a coordination of two noun phrases ("my wife" + "I"). It denotes a set containing two members and hence requires the plural verb "are".

Comment: My wife and I here is a compound subject. Why did you leave |is| at the top? I'd stay away from sets.

Comment: I changed 'NP' into 'noun phrase' because most ELLs are not familiar with such an abbreviation. If you don't like it, please roll it back.

Comment: @BenKovitz The head of the NP is "set" which is singular and hence takes a singular verb. And it's not even a coordination with "and"!

Answer (score 2):

## Plural subject

People don't normally perceive "my wife and I" as singular.

There *are* many situations where you can use a singular verb with a plural subject to make the listener *think of* the subject as singular. [Here's an answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/130689/6700) that gives a few illustrations of that. That doesn't work with "my wife and I", since even though those might be one whole family, the word **and** reinforces the perception that they are two people. In British English, even the singular noun "family" often takes a plural verb.

## Proximity agreement

Regarding proximity agreement, where the verb only agrees with the part of the subject closest to the verb and disagrees with another part of the subject, that works with **or**, not with **and**.* The main reason why proximity agreement is needed is because part of the subject is singular and part is plural, so there is no way to make the verb agree with both parts:

> **Bob McClaskey is** singing tonight.
>   **The Three Irishmen are** singing tonight.
>   Bob McClaskey **or** The Three Irishmen **are** singing tonight.
>   The Three Irishmen **or** Bob McClaskey **is** singing tonight.

So, if you're both singing:

> I **and** my wife **are** singing tonight.

If only one of you will sing, and you haven't decided who yet:

> I **or** my wife **is** singing tonight.

The verb form **am** suggests so strongly that the subject should exclusively be "I" that people tend to reword the sentence rather than use proximity agreement to cover a compound subject including someone other than "I". For example, if you reversed the order of "I" and "my wife" in the previous example, you would probably say:

> My wife or I **will be** singing tonight.

to avoid the disorientation that results from "My wife or I **am** singing tonight." The verb form **am** clashes too strongly with "my wife" for proximity agreement to make up for it.

---

* <sub>That's not a rule, of course. [Here's a question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26051/6700) about a sentence where proximity agreement does work with "and".</sub>

Comment: In informal situations, you can also say "me and my wife is singing tonight."

Comment: @user178049 In informal situations, you can also say "Like, man, ză biss wih da attude wuh like oh man, y'know?" I think it's unwise to teach that to beginners, though. In standard, formal English, the verb agrees with the subject, and "I" denotes the speaker in this context. You should know that there's currently a fad on among linguists to equate regional, informal, and illiterate dialects with the central written tradition that defines the standard English that is [common across regions, nations, and time](http://bit.ly/2vQ93Lq). I recommend not going along with that fad.

Comment: You went too far. "Like, man.." isn't a good thing to teach. But the structure "Me and my friends.." is something that is mentioned in most reliable grammar books. (I'm not debating, btw. I even upvote this because I agree. I just think it's a good alternative to avoid the issue like "My wife or I am/is". )

Comment: @user178049 No "debate", but here's why I think teaching that sort of thing to beginners is a bad idea: The most important thing to establish when learning something new is "landmarks": the mental things you orient by as you learn everything else. This is why getting clear and rock-solid on pronunciation when you first start learning a language is such a huge advantage. Sloppy pronunciation and grammar are understood _in relation to_ the landmarks of clear, formal speech. It doesn't work the other way around. …

Comment: @user178049 …Have you ever had one of those bad teachers who insists on burying you in complexities and short-cuts right from day one? It's bad teaching because you're not ready for that until you've gotten the main landmarks burned into your brain. _Then_ you can understand complexities, exceptions, cut corners, sloppiness, abuse of notation, etc. "Me and my friends…" is one of those sloppy elocutions. It's unacceptable in formal speech and writing. Teaching it as part of "English grammar" to beginners does them a disservice because it obscures the principal landmarks.